# Is there a way in MySQL to do a “round robin” ORDER BY on a particular field in variable universe?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, round-robin

My list is a infinite universe, as an example, I would like to take a table such as this one:

```
+-------+------+
| group | name |
+-------+------+
|     1 | A    |
|     1 | B    |
|     1 | C    |
|     1 | D    |
|     1 | E    |
|     1 | F    |
|     1 | G    |
|     1 | H    |
|     1 | I    |
|     2 | J    |
|     2 | L    |
|     2 | M    |
|     3 | N    |
|     4 | O    |
|     4 | P    |
|     4 | Q    |
|     4 | R    |
|     4 | S    |
|     5 | U    |
|     6 | V    |
+-------+------+
```

And run a query that produces results in this order:

```
+-------+------+
| group | name |
+-------+------+
|     1 | A    |
|     2 | J    |
|     3 | N    |
|     4 | O    |
|     5 | U    |
|     6 | V    |
|     1 | B    |
|     2 | L    |
|     4 | P    |
|     1 | C    |
|     2 | M    |
|     4 | Q    |
|     1 | D    |
|     4 | R    |
|     1 | E    |
|     4 | S    |
|     1 | F    |
|     1 | G    |
|     1 | H    |
|     1 | I    |
+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select `group`, name from (
  select 
  t.*,
  @rn := if(`group` != @ng, 1, @rn + 1) as ng,
  @ng := `group`
  from t
  , (select @rn:=0, @ng:=null) v
  order by `group`, name
) sq
order by ng, `group`, name
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68051/3/0)</kbd>

To explain it a little...

```
  , (select @rn:=0, @ng:=null) v
```

This line is just a fancy way to initialize the variables on the fly. It's the same as omitting this line but having `SET @rn := 0; SET @ng := NULL;` before the `SELECT`.

Then the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is very important. In a relational database there is no order unless you specify it.

Here

```
  @rn := if(`group` != @ng, 1, @rn + 1) as ng,
  @ng := `group`
```

the first line is a simple check, if the value of `group` in the current row is different from the value of `@ng`. If yes, assign `1` to `@rn`, if not, increment `@rn`.
The order of the columns in the `SELECT` clause is very important. MySQL processes them one by one. In the second line, we assign the value of `group` of the **current** row to `@ng`. When the next row of the table is processed by the query, in the first line of the two above, `@ng` will therefore hold the value of the **previous** row.

The outer select is just cosmetics, to hide unnecessary columns. Feel free to ask if anything is still unclear. Oh, and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) you can read more about user defined variables in MySQL.
Note though, that needing variables is rather the exception. They often result in full table scans. Whatever you want to achieve with variables in select statements is often better done on application level, rather than database level.

Comment: beat me to it! i was 90% done writing my response (almost exactly the same) with a sql fiddle lol good job!

Comment: @fancyPants: Hi, I have been learning SQL for the past few weeks. I had to answer a question similar to the one asked above. The answer helped, but I don't really understand the syntax or logic. If you don't mind, could you please explain the meaning of the query, or least post a link to a tutorial where I can learn it?

Comment: @user3033194 I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @fancyPants - Thank you for your expalation!! For a while, I was getting confused between the alias "ng" and the local variable "@ng". You cleared a lot of doubts!